# Getting Promise's and yield's to work together

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a `Promise` created, and I can't seem to get `yield` to work alongside of it. I have look at lots of docs/tutorials, and I don't think that I am quite grasping it yet. I am not sure which part is wrong.

From what I have read, I need a `next().value` when calling my generator, so that is what I am doing in this function:

```
exports.query = function(sql, values){
    var q2 = query2(sql, values);
    return q2.next().value;
};
```

Next I have the `generator`, which contains the `yield`:

```
function* query2(sql, values){
    yield doQuery(sql, values);
};
```

Finally I run the query and save it in the `Promise()`

```
function doQuery(sql, values){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        conn.query(sql, values, function(err, r){
            if(err){
                reject(err);
            }else{
                resolve(r);
            }
        });
    }).then(function(r){return r;});
}
```

Now when I want to use this, I call it like this:

```
var rows = conn.query("select * from groups");
console.log(rows);
```

The result of the `console.log()` is

```
{}
```

I know it shouldn't be that because without the `yield`/`Promise()` I get the correct data.

Maybe a `Promise` isn't necessary, but from what I am reading it seems like it might be. What am I doing wrong?

BTW, I am executing like so:

```
./node --harmony /myfile.js
```

Comment: Are you using **ECMA-6** - enabled browser (or non-browser platform)?

Comment: I forgot to add the tag `node`, so to answer your question, I am using Node.js

Comment: `var rows = conn.query("select * from groups");` - don't you mean `doQuery` or `query2`? looks like a typo.

Comment: I want to execute `query()` from the outside, which executes `query2()` which executes `doQuery()`. Maybe I have something(s) backwards in the logic?

Comment: What exactly do you think the generator is doing right there?

Comment: I thought that it would be getting the result of the callback from `Promise.then()` aka `r`

Answer (score 0):

`Promise.prototype.then` returns a new `Promise`, so you're logging an instance of `Promise`, not the actual value. Calling `console.log` in the function supplied to the then method will log the actual value (unless an error occured.)

Comment: How do I return the result to `exports.query()`?

Comment: The value can't be used in `exports.query` if `Promise` is used. You may, though, use the value in the callback supplied to `Promise.prototype.then`. For example `Promise.resolve(42).then((val) => val * 2)` would create a Promise resolved with the value 42 and then create a new Promise resolved with the value 84. You can chain multiple callbacks with `Promise.prototype.then` and `Promise.prototype.catch`, but you can't get the value out of the `Promise` (as far as I know.)